# Eclipse : Importing Existing Projects into workspace

Tags: eclipse

We have a Existing project downloaded from server  which was build on Maven .
(this is in the form of Folder Structure )

While  import that project in Eclipse , should i use

**Existing Projects into workspace**

Or

**File System**

Please guide me

Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have an existing **project**, then you must have a `.project` file. Check for that, and if you do have, you should use the **Existing Projects into workspace** option, and select the root folder of your project.

Since you have a Maven project, you could also import it as **Existing Maven Projects**, given that you have the Maven plugin installed in your eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

If you import a project into the workspace the files remain in their original locations. I do not know how to avoid this.
Often (always) I would like to have a copy of the files in the workspace and leave the project I imported it from in its original location untouched.
A frequent use-case is that I have a project and wish to make some changes to it to test out something without affecting the main project. 
Thanks John

Answer (score 0):

File -> Import... -> General -> Existing Project into Workspace -> Select the archive file by clicking Browse button -> Select the checkbox * Copy projects into workspace.  (this answers user462990's question). This way the project is copied into the workspace and the main project is not affected.

If you use "File -> Import... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects" you don't get the option to copy projects into workspace.